# Ограничить ввод двух точек

Tags: swift, uitextfield

Необходимо при вводе в UITextField с клавиатуры Decimal Pad:

1. заменять запятую на точку
2. запретить ввод двух точек

Я сделал так, но эти условия конфликтуют друг с другом:

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

 if string == "," {
   textField.text! += "."
   return false
 }

 let dotsCount = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
   if dotsCount > 0 && string == "." {
   return false
 }
 return true
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста с решением

Comment: можно подробнее? если введена запятая, заменить на точку. если в любой момент времени введена точка после точки (включая измененную запятую), убрать вновь введенный символ?

Comment: При вводе запятой на клавиатуре Decimal Pad, в строку вводилась точка. И если строка уже содержит точку, второй раз точку ввести нельзя было, так как данные со строки будут конвертироваться в Double.

Comment: ааа. так бы и написали. ок

Comment: с decimal pad нельзя ввести запятую

Comment: почему нет?
по моим региональным стандартам, у меня вместо точки запятая.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поменять условия местами и добавить проверку на запятую

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let dotsCount = textField.text!.componentsSeparatedByString(".").count - 1
    if dotsCount > 0 && (string == "." || string == ",") {
        return false
    }

    if string == "," {
        textField.text! += "."
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Ответ, как и думал на поверхности. Еще раз спасибо!!!