# XCode. Контроль разделителя разрядов. Как правильнее и эффективнее?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, apple, uitextfield

начало здесь: [Ограничить ввод двух точек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/467693/%D0%9E%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA)

А можно заставить DecimalPad: 1. сразу вводить вместо запятой точку? 2. проверять, чтобы не было повторных точек/запятых?

Ведь DecimalPad на то и создан, чтобы в поле, где нужны только числа, вводить только цифры и разделитель разрядов! А получается, нужно ещё и проверять, что у тебя другая страна и в ней вместо точки - запятая. И что могут два раза точку нажать.

Запятая/точка на клавиатуре появляются четко при изменении страны. И когда у тебя Штаты - на запятую уже проверять не надо. А вот если Россия - появляется запятая. Может быть эта проверка как то реализуется локализацией?

Ну и с двумя точками вопрос остается ...

Answer (score 1):

У `NSDecimalNumber` есть метод `-initWithString:locale:`, можете конвертировать им, это вам поможет избавиться от проверки запятая-точка.

Касательно проверки на две точки - в интернетах ничего умного предложить не могут, кроме того, что у вас уже есть.